# Terraform - use resource name and string for name

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

strange question. Can I, instead of using a variable, also use the resource property of an resource + a string to construct a name:

For example:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsgvmss" {
  name     = **"NSG - azurerm_resource_virtual_machine_scale_set.vmss.name"** 
  location = azurerm_resource_group.rgapp.location 
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rgapp.name
}
```

this works of course with variables like "NSG, ${var.vssname}" but again,

was wondering if i can use the resource name of the object in TF as well

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is called [string interpolation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html). Also see [expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html) (which isn't as pre-0.12-centric)

```
...
 name     = "NSG - ${azurerm_resource_virtual_machine_scale_set.vmss.name}"
...
```

Comment: The reference for "interpolation" in the 0.12 docs is https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#interpolation -- interpolation is part of "string templates" in 0.12, along with the two new template directives.